# Java-spring webservice client template returns partial output

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am hitting Mainframe services using spring webservice template as soap request. I am able to make the http connection and hit the service, but returns the partial output:

Actual response should be

```
  <headerOutputs>
     <RTNCODE>0</RTNCODE>
  </headerOutputs>
  <dataOutputs>
     <row>BI</row>
     <row>FSG</row>
    </dataOutputs>
```

But the code returns only headeroutputs 
0

I am getting proper response in soapUI tool.

log:

```
-- 2017-01-03 11:30:39.821 -- Sent request [SaajSoapMessage {urn:cws}request]
-- 2017-01-03 11:30:39.990 -- Received response [SaajSoapMessage headerOutputs] for request [SaajSoapMessage {urn:cws}request]
-- 2017-01-03 11:30:39.990 -- Soap response from sendXMLAndRecieveStream :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><headerOutputs><RTNCODE>0</RTNCODE></headerOutputs>
```

Comment: The actual response you list is not valid XML, there are two root nodes (or the root node is missing).

Comment: The complete response from soap ui tool :                                                                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <headerOutputs>
         <RTNCODE>0</RTNCODE>
      </headerOutputs>
      <dataOutputs>
         <row>BI</row>
         <row>FSG</row>
        </dataOutputs>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Are you saying that webservice considers <headeroutput> as the root element and ignoring <dataoutputs>